# Getting a list of youtube users

Tags: php, video, youtube, youtube-api

I want to get a list of all youtube usernames, preferably sorted out by time of registration. Is this possible? Is there an API call to do that?

Comment: I _really really_ doubt that.

Comment: Yes, Google would just LOVE to facilitate the spamming of their userbase...

Comment: I doubt you can. It's like asking for the list of all Gmail accounts.

Comment: crawling could be an answer for this but still limited :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is doubtful that you can get a list of users from YouTube see comments above. please see the [developers_guide_php](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html) for what you can do with the YouTube PHP API

Comment: Can you provide a summary and not just the link.

Comment: Yes, from your original post I'd assumed that you were linking to a call to do what the OP asked. The current form explains things much better.